# Angular date filter not working with Stripe timestamp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timestamp

I have a timestamp supplied by Stripe's API. 1397166153.

However when using it in the most simplest form `{{ 1397166153 | date }}` I get: Jan 17, 1970 when in fact it should be Apr 10, 2014.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I always run all of my timestamps through a function, as JavaScript epoch is in milliseconds, and the Stripe response epoch is in seconds.

```
$scope.timestamp = function(epoch){
    return (epoch * 1000);
};
```

Then, in your template:

```
 <p>{{ timestamp(1397166153) | date }}</p>
```

Alternatively, if you need to just do it once, you can always do it inline:

```
 <p>{{ (1397166153 * 1000) | date }}</p>
```

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the timestamp is in Seconds.

```
var seconds = 1397166153; //your value
var ms = seconds * 1000;

new Date(seconds) // Fri Jan 16 1970 21:06:06 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
new Date(ms) // Thu Apr 10 2014 15:42:33 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

I'm not sure what format Stripe sends it back in. But I've always had to convert to a `Date` object or to `ms` to work with Angular date filters.

Comment: Yes the timestamp was in seconds. Thanks for the help.

Comment: fantastic answer! most helpful thing I found on the internet today :) (full disclosure: as a homeless person I typically dont get to use the internet very much)